# Клонирование свойств прототипа родителя в прототип ребенка

Tags: наследование, prototype, javascript

Доброй ночи. Столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть примерно следующая конструкция:

```
/**
* Создаем объект класса, пихаем в его прототип свойства
*/
var ParentClass = new Function;
var pContainer = ParentClass.prototype;
pContainer[<prop_name>] = <prop_value>

/**
* Создаем дитё, задача - пихнуть в прототип cContainer-а свойства класса- родителя, но так, чтобы при изменении свойства прототипа родителя в ребенке - в прототипе родителя значения не менялись
*/
var ChildClass = new Function;
var cContainer = ChildClass.prototype;

// ДОлжно было прокатить .... не прокатило :(
Extends(cContainer, ParentClass);

function Extends( child, parent ) {
  var cProto = child.__proto__;
  var pProto = parent.prototype;
  var Ext = new Function;
  Ext.prototype = pProto;
  Ext.constructor();
  cProto = Ext.prototype; 
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, с функцией Extends :D

P.S. Прошу не смеяться с функции Extends. Как я только уже не пробовал: и eval-ом, и чем только не пробовал. Главное, чтобы объект ChildClass-а был инстансом от роителя.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Поиском пользуемся :)

[тыц](http://hashcode.ru/questions/106197/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую разгребстись :D

Comment: А мне очень нравится [inherits](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-176) из backbone.js

Comment: @Spectre - а мне не очень нравиться backbone.js ;D

Comment: обоснуйте, что именно? философия? реализация? code style? и по-подробнее, а ещё хотелось бы услышать альтернативу в нише занимаемой сабжем

Comment: В первую очередь философию.

######погуглил за вас - [тыц](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882184/backbone-js-alternatives-that-plays-ball-with-jquery)

Comment: клоны(`Spine` и т.п.) за альтернативу считать? такие монстры как `SproutCore` и `Ember` тоже не альтернатива. `Knockout.js` - альтернатива, но уж слишокм альтернативная. но так всё же, чем филосовия не устроила? просто интересно ваше мнение

Comment: @Spectre тут проблема не в самой библиотеке. Вот например возьмем тэг (по сути компонент) video. Какой минимум нужен для того, что-бы его использовать? Правильно - просто написать html. При это в DOM'e ничего кроме video не будет.

На самом деле я идеализирую, в реальном мире, на данный момент, кроссбраузерных идеалогически верных в этом смысле решений нет но, если вам действительно интересно что я имею введу - погуглите JS библиотеку `x-tags` (кросс-браузерности нет и близко, но суть уловите)
****
[видео по теме](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2txPYQOWBtg&feature=BFa&list=PL56D792A831D0C362)

Answer (score 1):

В JS не простые переменные копируются по ссылке. Т.е. по значению копируются только цифры, строки, bool, и т.д., но объекты, массивы и функции копируются по ссылке. в библиотеке underscore есть куча методов для работы с массивами и объектами, среди которых есть .clone() который возвращает новый объект с точно таким же набором простых свойств, копируя их по значению. Для копирования полностью всего объекта нужно написать нечто типа такого: (показываю на примере одной модели из моего проекта)

```
profile.prototype.clone = function(){
    var q = new profile();
    for(var i in this){
        if(typeof this[i] == 'function')
            q[i] = this[i];
        else
            q[i] = _.clone(this[i]);
    }
    return q;
}
```

т.е. тут я перебираю все свойства своего объекта и если это функция, то копирую ее в новый, а если другое значение, то отдаю на клонирование библиотеке Underscore.

---

Если нужно просто взять и сделать объект инстансом родителя, то возможно поможет вот такой пример с http://javascript.ru/tutorial/object/inheritance

```
function extend(Child, Parent) {
    var F = function(){ };
    F.prototype = Parent.prototype;
    Child.prototype = new F();
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
    Child.superclass = Parent.prototype;
}
```

Comment: > .clone() который возвращает новый объект с точно таким же набором простых свойств, копируя их по значению. Для копирования полностью всего объекта нужно написать нечто типа такого

Чего? 

> Create a shallow-copied clone of the object. Any nested objects or arrays will be copied by reference, not duplicated.

[_.clone(object)](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#clone)

     var a = _.clone(_); // эквивалентно var a = _.extend({}, _);
     a.identity
     //
     function(value) {
        return value;
     }

и чем же это ваш `clone` лучше?

Comment: _.clone() не эвивалентен _.extend().

Не понял вопроса в конце. Возможно я не понял вопроса автора.

Comment: для копирования объекта ваша обёртка над `_.clone` лишняя, достаточно и самой функции.

>.clone() не эвивалентен .extend().

взгляните на исходники [_.clone](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-70) и убедитесь, что в случае копирования объекта - эквивалентно

Comment: В моем случае она не лишняя, поскольку методы моего объекта при клонировании следующим образом return _.clone(this); будут превращены в пустые объекты, плюс мне необходимо было чтобы метод клон был именно у моего объекта, а не передавать мой объект во внешнюю функцию.

В общем случае методы clone и extend не эквивалентны. В вашем примере, когда подается пустой объект, то возвращаемый результат одинаков. В исходниках clone как раз и применяется этот частный случай. А функция extend возвращает новый объект, но если свойства объекта-"предка" являются объектом, то они будут скопированы по ссылке.