# Переопределение свойства заданного Object.defineProperty({configurable: true})

Tags: javascript, наследование, клонирование

У меня такая проблема. Мне нужно изменить свойство объекта защищённого от переопределения функцией `Object.defineProperty({configurable: true})`.
Я пытаюсь сделать это через наследование, которого конечно нет в JavaScript. Для этого беру функции которые предложены для таких задач гурами `JavaScript: extend(Child, Parent) и mixin(dst, src)`

```js
function extend(Child, Parent) {
    var F = function() { }
    F.prototype = Parent.prototype
    Child.prototype = new F()
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child
    Child.superclass = Parent.prototype    
}

// копирует все свойства из src в dst,
// включая те, что в цепочке прототипов src до Object
function mixin(dst, src){
 // tobj - вспомогательный объект для фильтрации свойств,
 // которые есть у объекта Object и его прототипа
 var tobj = {}
 for(var x in src){
  // копируем в dst свойства src, кроме тех, которые унаследованы от Object
  if((typeof tobj[x] == "undefined") || (tobj[x] != src[x])){
   try {
    dst[x] = src[x];
   } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error property: " + x);
   }
  }
 }
 // В IE пользовательский метод toString отсутствует в for..in
 if(document.all && !document.isOpera){
  var p = src.toString;
  if(typeof p == "function" && p != dst.toString && p != tobj.toString &&
   p != "\nfunction toString() {\n    [native code]\n}\n"){
   dst.toString = src.toString;
  }
 }
}

// Мой код
var myKeyboardEvent = function() {
    this.getLastElement = function() {
        return this[this.length-1];
    }
}

extend(myKeyboardEvent, KeyboardEvent);

//elem может быть любое поле <input type="text" name="elem" id="elem">
function pressKey(elem){
 var evt = new myKeyboardEvent("keypress");
 mixin(myKeyboardEvent.prototype, new KeyboardEvent("keypress"));
 elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

pressKey(elem);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="elem" id="elem">
```

Мой код вылетает по ошибке на `dispatchEvent`:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on
>   'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'.

Мне надо переопределить свойство `isTrusted` в объекте возвращаемом `KeyboardEvent`.

Как нибудь вообще можно корректно наследовать встроенные объекты JavaScript?

Comment: А какую проблему вы пытаетесь решить таким способом?

Comment: _Я пытаюсь сделать это через наследование, которого конечно нет в JavaScript_ - ну если вы решили не пользоваться наследованием, это еще не значит, что его нет :)

Comment: У меня есть расширение для браузеров Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/linkclicker/hoobpdoclliidciecjifpikpnopjpmkh?hl=ru
Я написал для него функцию эмитации набра строки

Comment: Вот что я нашёл по тегам на этом ресурсе, но пока не проверял:
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/129804/Клонирование-свойств-прототипа-родителя-в-прототип-ребенка

Comment: И насколько я читал эту тему, проблема с наследованием встроенных объектов существует. Причём ведёт себя по разному в разных браузерах.

Comment: в **не можете** переопределить  _isTrusted_ в событиях

Comment: Могу, после создания наследника объекта. Но функция dispatchEvent даёт ошибку на такой объект, что и приведено в примере.

Comment: ЗАДАЧА ОБОЙТИ ОГРАНИЧЕНИЕ Object.defineProperty({configurable: true})!!! С точки зрения нормальных языков программирования C, Pascal -  в этом проблем нет. Я вообще не понимаю зачем разработчики засунули "isTrusted" в свой объект. Но коли уж они это сделали, я хочу его изменить.

Comment: А с чего вы взяли что где-то используется _Object.defineProperty({configurable: true})_?

Comment: Эмпирическим путём проверил, попытавшись переопределить это свойство этим же оператором. В недоязыках типа JavaScript это единственно рабочий метод. Но надо заметить, проверял только в Хроме, ибо у меня расширение написано на нём.

Comment: как раз если бы configurable было true - то переопределить свойство можно было бы.

Comment: В общем это бесполезное занятие. Я всё таки создал объект с isTrasted=true, а dispatchEvent() его всё равно передал в состоянии false. Выводы: 1) Создавать корректные клоны встроенных объектов на JavaScript не возможно. 2) Наследование тоже.

Comment: какие-то неверные выводы